# How to create and sign a transaction by myself

Tags: polkadot-js, extrinsic, transactions, signing, documentation

I am developing the tool to create and sign a transaction, but I find nothing about the format of a transaction before signing. Could you please help me to find out the document about this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a guide here:
https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/build-transaction-construction

////////////////////////////////
...must have more characters...

Comment: Thank you so much. I think we can use https://polkadot.js.org/docs/ to generate/sign a transaction.